# Sum of i.i.d. random variables for which Chebyshev inequalities are tight

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, concentration-of-measure

[Chebyshev's inequalities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_inequality): Let $X$ be a random variable with finite expected value $\mu$ and finite non-zero variance $\sigma^{2}$. Then for any real number $\delta > 0$,

$$ \Pr[|X - \mu| \geq \delta\sigma] \leq \frac {1}{\delta^{2}}$$

There is a tight example in wiki, $X_c$ is a random variable with $\sigma = 1/c$:
$$
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
&\Pr[X_c = -1] = \frac{1}{2c^{2}}  \\
&\Pr[X_c = 0] = 1 - \frac{1}{c^{2}}  \\
&\Pr[X_c = 1] = \frac{1}{2c^{2}}  \\
\end{aligned}
\right.
$$
If $\delta = c$, then we have
$$ \Pr[|X - \mu| \geq \delta\sigma] = \Pr[|X| \geq 1] = \frac {1}{\delta^{2}}$$
But for $\delta > c$, it is not tight.
Is there another example that is tight for infinite large $\delta$?

In addition, suppose $X_{1}, X_{2}, \ldots, X_{n}$ are i.i.d. random variables with finite expected value $\mu$ and finite non-zero variance $\sigma^{2}$.
According to Chebyshev's inequalities:
$$\Pr\left[\left|\sum_{i}^{n}X_{i} - n\mu\right| \geq \delta n\sigma\right] \leq \frac{1}{n\delta^{2}}$$
Is there also an (asymptotic) tight example for $\{ X_{i} \}_{i}$?

Comment: Also [crossposted to stats.SE](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/590536/6633) where it has received a different answer.

Answer (score 4):

For your first question, consider a r.v. $X$ with finite first and second moment, variance $\sigma^2>0$ and w.l.o.g. $\mu=E(X)=0$. Assume that the Chebyshev inequality $$P(|X|\geq\varepsilon)\leq\frac{\sigma^2}{\varepsilon^2}$$ is tight for all $\varepsilon\geq\varepsilon_0$. Let $f_X$ be the PDF of $X$. Then
$$P(|X|\geq\varepsilon)=\int_\varepsilon^\infty f_X(x)+f_X(-x)dx=\sigma^2\varepsilon^{-2}$$ which implies $f_X(x)+f_X(-x)=2\sigma^2x^{-3}$ for all $x>\varepsilon_0$. But now we have run into a contradiction, since $$E(X^2)\geq\int_{\varepsilon_0}^\infty x^2(f_X(x)+f_X(-x))dx=\int_{\varepsilon_0}^\infty 2\sigma^2x^{-1}dx=\infty$$ contrary to our assumption that the second moment is finite, which is what allowed us to use the inequality in the first place.

Answer (score 3):

You can replace "infinite" by "2 or more."  That is, *there is no example where the inequality is tight for two distinct values.*

---

With no loss in generality (just change the units of measurement of $X$) simplify the notation by taking $\mu=0$ and $\sigma=1,$ so that

$$E\left[|X|^2\right] = \operatorname{Var}(X) = \sigma^2 = 1.$$

Let $Y = |X|^2,$ a positive variable, and write

$$S(y) = \Pr(Y\ge y) = \Pr(|X|^2 \ge y)$$

for its survival function.

Suppose there exist $\delta_2 \gt \delta_1 \gt 0$ for which the inequality is tight; that is,

$$S(\delta_1^2) = \Pr(Y \ge \delta_1^2) = \Pr(|X|\ge \delta_1) = \frac{1}{\delta_1^2},\quad S(\delta_2^2) =\Pr(Y \ge \delta_2^2) = \Pr(|X|\ge \delta_2) = \frac{1}{\delta_2^2}.$$

Then, because $S$ is non-increasing and non-negative,

$$\begin{aligned}
1 &= E\left[|X|^2\right]  = E[Y] = \int_0^\infty S(y)\,\mathrm{d}y \\
&\ge \int_0^{\delta_1^2} S(y)\,\mathrm{d}y\ +\ \int_{\delta_1^2}^{\delta_2^2} S(y)\,\mathrm{d}y\\
&\ge \int_0^{\delta_1^2} S(\delta_1^2)\,\mathrm{d}y\ +\  \int_{\delta_1^2}^{\delta_2^2}  S(\delta_2^2)\,\mathrm{d}y\\
&= \Pr(Y \ge \delta_1^2)\delta_1^2\ +\ \Pr(Y \ge \delta_2^2)\left(\delta_2^2 - \delta_1^2\right)\\
&= \frac{1}{\delta_1^2}\delta_1^2\ +\ \frac{1}{\delta_2^2}\left(\delta_2^2 - \delta_1^2\right)\\
&= 1 + \left(1 - \left(\frac{\delta_1}{\delta_2}\right)^2\right)\\
&\gt 1.
\end{aligned}$$

This contradiction shows the hypothetical existence of two tight equalities is false, *QED.*